# Consulta y impresión por Bluetooth no parecen los datos de consultados tanto la consulta y Impresión. ANDROID ESTUDIO JAVA

Tags: java, sql-server, android-studio, edittext

Al momento de escáner el producto por código de barra si realiza la consulta, aparece algunos datos en la aplicación pero el precio no aparece y en la impresión solo aparece el nombre del producto, estoy usando SQL Server and Sybase JDBC driver - Browse /jtds/1.3.1 para la conexión y consulta, pero si quito todo la integración de  Bluetooth para la impresión si aparece el precio, quisiera saber en que estoy mal les agradecería de sus apoyos.
Este es el código.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText dni;

    TextView descripcion;

    EditText categoria;

    EditText precios;

    EditText  cb;
    EditText clave;

    EditText unidad;


    public static final int PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH = 1;

    private final Locale locale = new Locale("id", "ID");
    private final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a", locale);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dni = findViewById(R.id.txtdni);
        clave = findViewById(R.id.lblclave);
        cb = findViewById(R.id.lblcb);
        descripcion = findViewById(R.id.lbldescripcion);
        categoria = findViewById(R.id.lblcategoria);
        precios = findViewById(R.id.lblprecio);

        unidad = findViewById(R.id.lblUnidad);


        dni.setOnClickListener(v -> consultarpersonal());
    }




    public Connection conexion(){
        Connection cnn =null;
        try {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            cnn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IP;databaseName=NOMBRE;user=Usuario;password=;");

        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return cnn;
    }



    public void consultarpersonal(){

        try {
            Statement stm= conexion().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stm.executeQuery("SELECT c.codigo,d.categoria,d.articulo,d.descripcion1,e.disponible,b.unidad,b.factor,d.preciolista,d.Estatus,D.PermisoRenglon,f.Direccion3, e.Almacen FROM CB C lEFT OUTER JOIN Art d on d.articulo=c.cuenta lEFT OUTER JOIN Artunidad b on b.Articulo=c.cuenta  and b.unidad=d.unidad lEFT OUTER JOIN artdisponible e on e.Articulo= c.Cuenta lEFT OUTER JOIN AnexoCta f ON f.Cuenta=c.Cuenta where d.estatus in('ALTA','PROTOTIPO','BLOQUEADOS') AND E.Almacen='ALPLA' AND C.codigo ='" + dni.getText().toString()+"'");
            if(rs.next()){

                dni = findViewById(R.id.txtdni);
                cb.setText(rs.getString(1));

                categoria.setText(rs.getString(2));
                clave.setText(rs.getString(3));
                descripcion.setText(rs.getString(4));
                alpla.setText(rs.getString(5));
                precios.setText(rs.getString(8));
               precios = findViewById(R.id.lblpre);
                unidad.setText(rs.getString(6));


            }
            dni.setText("");
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Por favor de introducir numero",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    public void doPrint(View view) {
        try {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH}, MainActivity.PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH);
            } else {
                BluetoothConnection connection = BluetoothPrintersConnections.selectFirstPaired();
                if (connection != null) {
                    EscPosPrinter printer = new EscPosPrinter(connection, 203, 48f, 32);



                    final String text = "[C]<img>" + PrinterTextParserImg.bitmapToHexadecimalString(printer,
                            this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawableForDensity(R.drawable.logo,
                                    DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW, getTheme())) + "</img>\n" +
                            "[L]\n" +
                            "[L]" + df.format(new Date()) + "\n" +
                            "[C]================================\n" +
                            "[L]"+      (descripcion.getText().toString())+ "\n" +
                            "[C]================================\n" +
                            "[C]================================\n" +
                            "[L]"+      (precios.getText().toString())+ "\n" +
                            "[C]================================\n" +
                            "[C]--------------------------------\n" +
                            "[L]Precios" + "\n" +
                            "[L]<qrcode>https://www.pagina</qrcode>\n";

                    printer.printFormattedText(text);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No printer was connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("APP", "Can't print", e);
        }
    }


}
```